# Rich Text field won't accept link

Tags: redactor, richtext

I am unable to insert a link into a Rich Text field.  The modal opens, I enter the data but nothing happens when I click ‘save’, no errors seem to be thrown.  I am able to insert a link to anther entry in the same modal. Field(s) are set to default and no plugins are being used.  The entries are both in a structure with no urls of their own, and in Craft Commerce product types.

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors in your browser's console when you click the "Insert" button?

Comment: Are you able to click the `HTML` button within Redactor? Just curious if anything is getting entered or if it is completely ignoring everything.

Comment: Facepalm, just got it.   I have addTrailingSlashesToUrls set to true and falsely thought it added one  .com/  but was wrong, as soon as I added / to the link back in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twas my own fault - I have addTrailingSlashesToUrls set to true and falsely thought it added one after .com/ but was wrong.  As soon as I added / to the link back in order.